# What is snarf in Javascript/ECMA?

Tags: javascript

I was looking through Mozilla's [JS in JS](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/narcissus/jsexec.js) code and came across the [snarf function](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/narcissus/jsexec.js#137). It's not defined in the javascript, it seems, just in the C version [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/js.c#3712). It isn't very well-commented, though. I Google searched this to no avail.

Is this a standard part of JavaScript? (My guess is no.) Is it some kind of extension? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not standard. It is the part of Mozilla's Narcissus (JS in JS interpreter implemented on top of SpiderMonkey). `snarf(filename)` grabs the content of the file and returns it as a string for further processing (e.g., evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

It loads a file and returns the contents of the file in a string.